# Magento 2 downloadable file in backend

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.0, importexport, export

I'm encountering a problem when using the native export module in admin.

I'm using an admin account with a specific role that can only access to catalog and system / export

If my first action is to go to system / export an trying to export products for example, the file is not generated and I'm redirected to my default admin page ( product list ).

If I'm visiting another page and come back to try the export again, it works.

I see that's because of the code which creates the file :

```
public function create(
        $fileName,
        $content,
        $baseDir = DirectoryList::ROOT,
        $contentType = 'application/octet-stream',
        $contentLength = null
    ) {
        if ($this->_auth->getAuthStorage()->isFirstPageAfterLogin()) {
            return $this->_redirect($this->_backendUrl->getStartupPageUrl());
        }
        return parent::create($fileName, $content, $baseDir, $contentType, $contentLength);
    }
```

In module-backend/App/response/Http/FileFactory.php

Can someone could explain me why the admin user needs to be redirected if a file is generated on the first page visited in back-office ?

I'm thinking about removing this redirection to solve my problem but I'm wondering if this redirection is related to security or something else.

Thank you

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. Did you ever find out why this is done?
As a workaround I now call the function setIsFirstPageAfterLogin on the session in my specific controller to negate this check.

Comment: Hello, I didn't fix it because my colleagues thinks it's related to security ... So we'd rather told the client if was not a good pratice to remove it. Still unsure why it's used.

Comment: Thanks! I found this SO thread explaining where it is used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748670/what-is-the-purpose-of-isfirstpageafterlogin-method-in-admin-session-model

We ran into this issue as well when the first page is the "orders" page. The first action of the user could be "Export > CSV", which also fails. It seems they haven't thought about those use cases ;)